# Render className with ternary nested If Els statement React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do have a small issue
I do need to render a className based on few conditions.
I have a Play button, Live button and general buttons. Most classes are the same, but I do need to add extra class to a play button.

My code so far is looking like this:

```
 className={`"Controller-Button player-btn icon" ${
          isSelected
            ? `${btnName === "PLAYER_LIVE" ? " live-button" : ""}`
            : `${btnName === "PLAYER_LIVE" ? " live-button" : ""}`
        }`}
```

And now I am stuck. I need to add extra condition before isSelecetd:
`btnName === "PLAYER_PLAY" ? " play-button" : ""` but i do have issue how properly put this in such render.
If I will add `btnName === "PLAYER_LIVE" ? " live-button" : "play-button"` this class wil be in all buttons.

Comment: why are the conditions the same?

Comment: I would advise you to move this logic into a function and use `if...else` instead of nested ternary conditions. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: _this class wil be in all buttons._ How is this class not in all of the buttons in the provided code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to move this logic into a function. Something like

```
const getClassName = () => {
  let className
  if (btnName === 'PLAYER_PLAY') {
    // applicable logic here for className here
  } else {
    // applicable logic here for className here
  }
  return className
}
```

Comment: thanks will move this to a function

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that:

```
const classes = ["Controller-Button", "player-btn", "icon"];
if(isSelected) {
  classes.push("live-button")
} else if(somethingCondition) {
   classes.push("someClass")
}
```

etc...

```
 className={classes.join(' ')}
```